# Google Cal API Python : Create a calendar with TimeZone setting not considered

Tags: python, timezone, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a little problem using the Google API for Google calendar when I try to create a new calendar.
Indeed the TimeZone of the calendar is not considered, the calendar is create but the TimeZone is the one by default.
The same thing for the Selected option of the calendar.

The code :

```
time_zone = 'Europe/Paris'
calendar = gdata.calendar.data.CalendarEntry()
calendar.title = atom.data.Title(text='testMaj1')
calendar.timezone = gdata.calendar.data.TimeZoneProperty(value=time_zone)
calendar.hidden = gdata.calendar.data.HiddenProperty(value='false')
calendar.selected = gdata.calendar.data.SelectedProperty(value='true')

new_calendar = client.InsertCalendar(new_calendar=calendar)
```

I've search for the different possibilities of timezone and I've found ( http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/adwords/docs/developer/adwords_api_timezones.html ) Europe/Paris so I tried it without success.
I test with another timezone and it's the same.

I've no error during the creation of the new calendar.

If you have some idea about this ... :)

Thank's

Comment: I have the same issues.  The bottomline is Google APIs are crap.  Have wasted days with different options. Following their API documentation literally but still the same results.